# Can I test the physical memory of a VPS or virtual machine?

Tags: memory, vps

Is there a memory test program I can run on an online VPS hosted instance?
Since it is a VPS I don't have access to the console or the memtest grub option.

I am troubleshooting random crashes (with no logging) and need to rule out memory issues.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have access to the physical host which the VPS or virtual machine is running on, the answer is no, unfortunately.

If you really suspect memory corruption may be an issue, ask your host to move the VPS to a different physical host. If it continues, then it's most probably a software issue.